# Unable to restart apache

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I was following [digitaloceans.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-centos-7) guide to setup a subdomain.
But now I'm having trouble restarting apache.

I have the following error:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status httpd.service` gave me this:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-04-18 18:11:36 UTC; 12s ago
     Docs: man:httpd(8)
           man:apachectl(8)
  Process: 1679 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 1678 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1678 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Apr 18 18:11:36 web-server systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 18 18:11:36 web-server systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 18 18:11:36 web-server kill[1679]: kill: cannot find process ""
Apr 18 18:11:36 web-server systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 18 18:11:36 web-server systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 18 18:11:36 web-server systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Apr 18 18:11:36 web-server systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

So I went on and did a sudo tail /var/log/httpd/error_log and got this :

```
(21)Is a directory: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/motomart.my.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(21)Is a directory: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/motomart.my.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(21)Is a directory: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/motomart.my.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(21)Is a directory: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/motomart.my.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
(21)Is a directory: AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/motomart.my.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Can any kind soul please help me out on this? Iam very new and couldnt figure what should I do next.

The Apache configuration snippet follows.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName portal.motomart.my
    ServerAlias www.portal.motomart.my
    DocumentRoot /var/www/motomart.my/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/motomart.my/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/motomart.my/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: hi Christopher, I apologize for slow learning but could you let me on more information on how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Your logs are telling you exactly why Apache is unable to start:

```
AH00091: httpd: could not open error log file /var/www/motomart.my.
AH00015: Unable to open logs (21)Is a directory:
```

Make sure that you are not trying to use a *directory* as a log file in yout Apache configuration.

Comment: this maybe a dumb question to ask, but how can I create a log file?

I have the following conf :


`<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName portal.motomart.my 
    ServerAlias www.portal.motomart.my 
    DocumentRoot /var/www/motomart.my/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/www/motomart.my/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/motomart.my/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>`

Comment: Does the directory actually exist in a swate which is writable by Apache?